# learning OO within javascript: error - cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript

I believe I've overlooked something I'm doing. I'm attempting to play around with objects and have some fun but I'm getting into this strange bug. I've used OO in C++/C#.

I create a *game environment* object that will contain all the information about this game.

I then created a validation tool (object) that houses regex tests for valid input, in which I call and pass into then return the test result.

With those objects, I then created a `launch();` function that prompts the user for a user name and validates with the tool. It's in this call that I run into this bug.

I'm not sure if what I'm doing is legal in JS considering this bug.

```js
launch();

function launch() {
  var userNameInput = prompt("Please enter your name:", "User Name");
  if (gameEnv.player(userNameInput)) {
    alert("Please enter only letters for a username.");
    location.reload(true);
  }
}

var gameEnv = {
  playerName: "",
  set player(input) {
    if (validationTool.LetterValidator(input)) {
      this.playerName = input;
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  },

}

var validationTool = {
  letterOnlyValidation: /^[a-zA-Z^\s]+$/,
  LetterValidator: function(input) {
    return letterOnlyValidation.test(input);
  },
}
```

Comment: move the call to launch to below where you initialize your gameEnv variable

Comment: `letterOnlyValidation` should be `this.letterOnlyValidation`

Comment: You return different values from a setter (`set player(input)`)? That will not work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unless you need to be compatible with older versions of JavaScript, ES6 JavaScript has actual `class` declarations you can use for OO.

Even with older JS the way to create an instance of a class is to define it using a `function`, and create new instance using `new`.

The problem with the particular code here:

```
var gameEnv = {
  playerName: "",
  set player(input) {
    if (validationTool.LetterValidator(input)) {
      this.playerName = input;
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  },

}
```

...is that you've defined a setter for `player` with `set`, but there is no getter, so player can be set, but it can't be read back.

Also, since this object hasn't been created properly as a class instance using `new`, the `this` here refers to the global `this`, not to object itself.

Comment: I was following a few tutorials on how objects are created in JS, and I came across this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_object_accessors_set

In which, they create an object with this 'object literal' (although, after looking at ES6  I'm switching to ES6) and they only had a setter with `set`. I do understand without a getter it's not read back but this was purely for experimental purposes.

Comment: No, `this` works as it should. There isn't something magic that happens to `this` for the methods when you create an object with `new`. `var gameEnv = { set player(input) { console.log(this);}}; gameEnv.player = "test";`

Comment: @Robolisk You just got a first person experience why you should not use w3schools.com. There are a lot of incorrect information on that site.

Answer (score 1):

few issues here:

- The set syntax binds an object property, should use `=` to assign value.
- order matters

```html
var gameEnv = {
  playerName: "",
  set player(input) {
    if (validationTool.LetterValidator(input)) {
      this.playerName = input;
      alert("player name set");
    } else {
      alert("Please enter only letters for a username.");
    }
  },

}

var validationTool = {
  letterOnlyValidation: /^[a-zA-Z^\s]+$/,
  LetterValidator: function(input) {
    return this.letterOnlyValidation.test(input);
  },
}

launch();

function launch() {
  var userNameInput = prompt("Please enter your name:", "User Name");
  gameEnv.player = userNameInput;
}
```